None keep showing in the output: any one knows why?
I am trying to write a program to check if a user input number is odd or even using at least three methods, however for the two last methods it keeps showing the None keyword to the console
# This is the first method
user_number = int(input("Please enter the number you want to check\n"))
message_to_print = "Your number is even" if user_number % 2 == 0 else print("Your number is odd")
print(message_to_print)
# This is the second method
user_number_check = (user_number / 2).is_integer()
print("Your number is even" if user_number_check else print("Your number is odd"))
# This is the third method
if user_number_check:
    print("Your number is even ")
elif not user_number_check:
    print("Your number is odd ")


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


message_to_print = "Your number is even" if user_number % 2 == 0 else print("Your number is odd")


The return value of a call to print is always None. Thus if the number input is odd, message_to_print is always None.
You likely wanted:
message_to_print = "Your number is even" if user_number % 2 == 0 else "Your number is odd"
print(message_to_print)

Likewise:

user_number_check = (user_number / 2).is_integer()
print("Your number is even" if user_number_check else print("Your number is odd"))


Suffers the same issue and should be:
user_number_check = (user_number / 2).is_integer()
print("Your number is even" if user_number_check else "Your number is odd")


Ok, is there any way to get rid of it? I'm a beginner I try to learn

Yes. As explained in the answer, don't print the result of print. You can see this with any string. Run print(print('foo')) in your Python interpreter.
